# How can I insert an object in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, object

I want to convert my object status field that is would be modified specifically.
I have found the answer but no fill my goal that's why I updated my question

I have objects like this below:

```
   Items = [
  {
    "id": 9,
    "alias": "5cbe5c1c-e36b-422d-beb3-225a8e549bf1",
    "name": "sfasf",
    "status": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "alias": "ed8a6921-c2c2-4a49-8893-5bf5c2bc0d98",
    "name": "Test",
    "status": 2
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "alias": "ed8a921-c2c2-4a49-8893-5bf5c2bc0d98",
    "name": "Test",
    "status": 3
  }
]
```

I need to convert my object like below or I need to print like belows:

```
    [
  {
    "id": 9,
    "alias": "5cbe5c1c-e36b-422d-beb3-225a8e549bf1",
    "name": "sfasf",
    "status": {
      "1": "ACTIVE"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "alias": "ed8a6921-c2c2-4a49-8893-5bf5c2bc0d98",
    "name": "Test",
    "status": {
      "2": "INACTIVE"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "alias": "ed8a921-c2c2-4a49-8893-5bf5c2bc0d98",
    "name": "Test",
    "status": {
      "3": "DELETED"
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example:

```js
const possibleStatus = {
  1: 'ACTIVE',
  2: 'INACTIVE'
}

Items.map(item => ({...item, status: {[item.status]: possibleStatus[item.status]}}))
```

Update: addded lookup via `possibleStatus`

---

If [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) `??` is available, I would add a fallback for undefined status:

```js
Items.map(item => ({...item, status: {[item.status]: possibleStatus[item.status] ?? `UNDEFINED STATUS ${item.status}`}}))
```

but only if this is display logic. In case of business logic, I'd rather check for valid values and throw an exception, e.g. encapsulated in a function mapping the status string to the object.

Answer (score 3):

```js
let statusTable = {
  
  1: "ACTIVE",
  2: "INACTIVE",
  3: "DELETED"
}

let Items = [
  {
    "id": 9,
    "alias": "5cbe5c1c-e36b-422d-beb3-225a8e549bf1",
    "name": "sfasf",
    "status": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "alias": "ed8a6921-c2c2-4a49-8893-5bf5c2bc0d98",
    "name": "Test",
    "status": 2
  },
    {
    "id": 6,
    "alias": "ed8a921-c2c2-4a49-8893-5bf5c2bc0d98",
    "name": "Test",
    "status": 3
  }
]

let result = Items.map(el => {
   el.status = { [el.status]: statusTable[el.status] }
   return el;
})

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I found your answer useful, but I have also answer, please clarify me which is better            Items.some(function(obj) {
            if (obj.status === 1) {
              obj.status = { 1: 'ACTIVE' }
            }
            if (obj.status === 2) {
              obj.status = { 2: 'INACTIVE' }
            }
            if (obj.status === 3) {
              obj.status = { 3: 'DELETED' }
            }
          })

Comment: Well the answer from sebastian is almost the same like mine, but works the same. His syntax is just shorter, i think this is the best way to go with

Comment: @Haronur well going with 3 if` statements is.. well yea... it doesnt look nice for me

Answer (score 2):

If this is json, first you might want to parse it with JSON.parse, like following:

```
let parse = JSON.parse(yourJsonObj)
```

Next you get your array, which you need to modify. You can use map method and return a new array with the data you need:

```
let newData = parse.map(item => {
  item.status = { [item.status]: "INACTIVE" };
  return item;
});
```

Then you can go back and stringify it back if needed with JSON.stringify(newData).

The rules by which you set INACTIVE or ACTIVE I don't know, but this is the gist of it.

Comment: Why are you always using `2` as the key? It looks like the key should be the original numeric `status` value.

Comment: As I'm sure you know, many people misuse the term JSON to refer to the object/array literals, not strings. And the code that was in the question made it clear what they were working with.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this solution be useful for you.

```
Items = [
  {
    "id": 9,
    "alias": "5cbe5c1c-e36b-422d-beb3-225a8e549bf1",
    "name": "sfasf",
    "status": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "alias": "ed8a6921-c2c2-4a49-8893-5bf5c2bc0d98",
    "name": "Test",
    "status": 2
  }
]

Items = Items.map(item => {
item.status = item.status == 1 ?  { "1": "ACTIVE" } : { "2": "INACTIVE" }
return item;
} )

console.log(Items);
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have indicated, `map()` is the way to go.

I've stepped things out a little here in such a way that the system wouldn't have unintended consequences if a third property was introduced. The switch statement explicitly only changes things if the status is 1 or 2 and leaves things alone otherwise.

The other examples given are probably fine for your use case though.

```js
var items = [ { "id": 9, "alias": "5cbe5c1c-e36b-422d-beb3-225a8e549bf1", "name": "sfasf", "status": 1 }, { "id": 5, "alias": "ed8a6921-c2c2-4a49-8893-5bf5c2bc0d98", "name": "Test", "status": 2 },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "alias": "ed8a921-c2c2-4a49-8893-5bf5c2bc0d98",
    "name": "Test",
    "status": 3
  } ];



const process = () => {
  // render original
  const orig = document.querySelector('.original');
  orig.innerHTML = '';
  items.forEach(i => orig.innerHTML += `<li>${i.status}</li>`);
  
  
  var result = items.map(i => {
    switch(i.status) {
      case(1):
        i.status = {"1": "ACTIVE"}
        break;
      case(2):
        i.status = {"2": "INACTIVE"}
        break;
      case(3):
        i.status = {"3": "DELETED"}
        break;
      default:
        // if status is not 1, 2 or 3, do nothing to the object
        break;
    }
    // return the object
    return i

  })
  
  // render processed
  const res = document.querySelector('.results');
  res.innerHTML = '';
  items.forEach(i => res.innerHTML +=
  `<li>${JSON.stringify(i.status)}</li>`);
}

process()
```

```html
<div class="cols">
  <div>
  <p>Original</p>
    <ul class="original">

    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
  <p>Result</p>
    <ul class="results"></ul>
  </div>
```